# Kubuntu 18.04 Tor Browser don't use gtk theme set by .gtkrc-2.0

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, themes, gtk, tor

Tor browser is using light theme (breeze?) although in system settings i set arc-darker as theme for gtk apps. I tried setting GTK2_RC_FILES to my .gtkrc-2.0 but it didn't help. Is there a way to make it use arc theme, like, for example, firefox does?

This is how firefox looks

[image: This is how firefox looks]

And this is tor browser looks

[image: And this is tor browser looks]

Answer (score 1):

I installed torbrowser-launcher version 0.2.9-2 which provided me with the Tor browser which itself is based on Firefox 60.3.0esr:

[image: About Tor browser]

The point to note is that Firefox is and has been a gtk3 application since Firefox 46. So your gtkrc-2.0 settings will not be effective.

I suggest you look at **System Settings > Application Style > GNOME Application Style** and make a suitable choice there.

[image: GTK3 theme settings]

Comment: I tried those settings, but they doesn't seem to affect tor browser, but they do affect all other gtk apps, though.

Comment: Well, now that you know that .gtkrc-2.0 has nothing to do with Firefox, I hope you'll be able to figure things out. I don't have Tor on my Kubuntu system to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, Firefox is and has always been a GTK3 app since Firefox 46, which means that editing your .gtkrc-2.0 is unnescesarry. But, the reason Firefox follows your theme and not tor browser is because of this :

##### Tor-Browser runs with the `$HOME` variable set to `~/.tor-browser/app/Browser` instead of just `~/` to be more anonymous. Which means when you run tor-browser, the home directory for it is set to `~/.tor-browser/app/Browser`.

What you can do is create a symlink to your theme :

```
$ ln -s ~/.themes ~/.tor-browser/app/Browser/.themes
```

At least, this worked for me, on Arch Linux using the tor-browser package from the AUR.